# Use of Property file

Tags: java, properties

I am creating properties file for database connection..I have given the path of the file and I am storing properties using the function:

```
 public void setProperty(String key, String value) {
    properties.setProperty(key, value);
}
```

I have set the properties like:

```
"url","jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";"dbname","example";"user", "postgres";"Pass","123";
```

My question is when I am using my application in another system how could this properties file is useful (Actually I have gone through the "property file in java" tutorials but I was unable to understand how they are used).

In new system user name and password would be different,so how could this file be useful??

Comment: you can make multiple property files for using them on multiple systems?

Comment: good info to start with if you are looking into java property http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javaqa/2003-08/01-qa-0808-property.html

Comment: But how could I know the other users user name and password,I could specify him to create database with particular name but I can't ask him to change the credentials of mysql..That too I am making jar file of my application.So it is not possible to hard code.

Comment: The usefulness is, that you don't have to recompile your program, if you had fixed the values in the code. And you don't have to start with a long series of parameters `java MyDBprog -db=MySql -user me -pass 123 ...`

Answer (score 4):

> In new system user name and password would be different,so how could this file be useful??

It is useful *precisely because* the file *can* be different on different systems.  By putting the system-specific details into a file that can be changed on different systems, you avoid having to write different Java code for each different system.

> But how could I know the other users user name and password

In the scenario where you don't know, you have a number of alternatives, such as:

- telling the user to edit the properties file with a text editor,
- coding your application's installer to ask the for the username and password and then insert them into the properties file at install time, or
- providing a configuration tool or interface that allows the user to enter or update the properties.

---

By the way, it looks like you have invented a custom property file format.  You didn't need to do that.  The `java.util.Properties` class offers two *standard* formats and methods for reading and writing them.

Comment: Fine..what is the way to do this??I guess-initially setting the parameters when the program starts and reading parameters when needed and using the retrieved values in the code??

Comment: @user10101 - basically yes.  The `Properties` class can support all of these.

Comment: Thanks for your bullet points..Good choices,I could do any one of these but doing this would only change the credentials in the prop file(in the prop file which I have stored in specific path)..How could this result in change of the internal credentials which the other user sets during the installation??

Comment: @user10101 - you **update** the file during the installation process.

Answer (score 0):

At least to my understanding the idea of property files are to be **outside** of the jar file. I will describe my way to go - the basic idea is to use relative paths and always the same structure when you package your application:

- using deployment tool to create packages, easy to deploy. 
  For this I am using Maven, with a custom assembly descriptor which I provide to [maven-assembly-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/)
- such properties files as database configuration, in the project structure are located under */src/resources/config* (for example)
- in the assembly descriptor (which creates a zip file), all files from */src/resources/config* are moved to the root of the zip in directory config - so in */config* inside the zip file. */config* should be added to classpath using maven-jar-plugin configuration for example, or the maven-dependency-plugin.
- the main jar is located on the root level of the zip, and all other dependencies are in /lib folder (using the maven-dependency-plugin)

This way you ship a single zip file, which has inside structure like:

```
/

/config

/bin

/lib

<main jar file with manifest - the manifest contains all the classpath info - this info is automatically generated by the maven plugins>
```

When the credentials change, all you have to do is edit the properties file. Another matter is, if that's secure.